# bitnami elasticsearch helm chart vs official elastic helm chart vs ECK for production deployment

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, kubernetes-helm

I need some advice as to which approach I should adopt for the production deployment of a log analytics solution.

I have an on-prem Elasticsearch cluster that I am moving to the cloud (EKS on AWS).
I am a single person working on it so I need something that will provide me with production-grade deployment with minimal effort.

I have been able to deploy the [bitnami/elasticsearch](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/elasticsearch) helm chart but unfortunately, it uses the OSS version, which means I have to add a lot of other features myself.

The official elastic helm chart is the second option that I have not tried yet but should work. However in the repo it is [mentioned](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts#eck) that ECK is the preferred option.

ECK is the last option but I haven't seen any production-ready sample deployment file. Best available is [this](https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/blob/master/config/samples/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yaml) which is going to need some work.

So which is the best option that I should go with considering minimal pain now and in the future?
Another aspect to be considered is the licensing. Will the Elastic basic license come in the way if we want to offer the log analytics solution as an add-on to our main product? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've ended up deploying Bitnami's Elasticsearch on a seperate EC2 and never had to touch it again. Then I've deployed Kibana and Fluentd on K8s to collect/ship logs to elasticsearch and view and build charts and analytics using Kibana.

I've also written a detailed tutorial on how to deploy such setup on EKS:
https://www.shebanglabs.io/logging-with-efk-on-aws-eks/